# Should javascript be used for this?

Tags: javascript, smoothing

I was asked to turn this [flash movie](http://www.puntacana.com) into a javascript animation so it can be seen on ipads. I am new to javascript/jquery so Im not sure I did it the best way possible but,

**i got it working [here](http://www.hodaradesign.com/rotate). (jsfiddle)**

The problem is all the images together weigh almost 1000 kb. the animation is nowhere near smooth on anything but the latest versions of chrome and safari on a fast computer.  My question is whether javascript is the appropriate medium for such a thing. If so, are there techniques on making large images animate smoothly that I'm missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
    <title>Testing</title> 


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" language="javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Assets/jquery.effects.core.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Assets/jQueryRotate.2.1.js" language="javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Assets/jquery.transform.js" language="javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="Assets/jquery.transform-0.9.3.min.js" language="javascript"></script> 

<style type="text/css"> 
body {
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: white;
font-size: 10px;
font-family: arial,helvetica,verdana,sans-serif;
display: block;
}

div {
display: block;
}


#box {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 980px;
text-align: left;
background-color: #FCFAE9;
}

#top {
width: 980px;
height: 582px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
}

#tab {
background-color: #ccc;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 560px;
width: 960px;
height: 22px;
z-index: 2;
}

#jsbox {position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 132px; width:960px; height:450px; overflow:hidden; background:url(Assets/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#imageholder {position:relative; width:960px; height:450px; }

#green{top:0; left:0; position:absolute; display:none}

.palms {width:428px; height:539px;}

#apalm1 {top:20px; left:-150px; position:absolute}

#apalm2 {top:-150px; left:-50px; position:absolute}

#apalm3 {top:-200px; left:50px; position:absolute}

#apalm4 {top:250px; left:70px; position:absolute}

#apalm5 {top:-300px; left:400px; position:absolute}

#apalm6 {top:-300px; left:500px; position:absolute}

#apalm7 {top:40px; left:560px; position:absolute}

#apalm8 {top:170px; left:590px; position:absolute}

.palms>div{
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/palm.png) no-repeat;
        /* IE hack */
    background:none\9; /* Targets IE only */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="Assets/puntacana/palm.png", sizingMethod="crop");}   



#icon {top:215px; left:525px; width:396px; height:79px; position:absolute; display:none }
#icon>div {
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/text1.png) no-repeat;
        /* IE hack */
    background:none\9; /* Targets IE only */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="Assets/puntacana/text1.png", sizingMethod="crop");}  

#text2 {top:265px; left:545px; width:381px; height:28px; position:absolute; display:none}
#text2>div {
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/text2.png) no-repeat;
        /* IE hack */
    background:none\9; /* Targets IE only */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="Assets/puntacana/text2.png", sizingMethod="crop");}  

#text3 {top:265px; left:40px; width:307px; height:28px; position:absolute; display:none}
#text3>div {
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/text3.png) no-repeat;
        /* IE hack */
    background:none\9; /* Targets IE only */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="Assets/puntacana/text3.png", sizingMethod="crop");}  

#text4 {top:270px; left:650px; width:275px; height:28px; position:absolute; display:none}
#text4>div {
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/text4.png) no-repeat;
        /* IE hack */
    background:none\9; /* Targets IE only */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="Assets/puntacana/text4.png", sizingMethod="crop");}  

#text5 {top:270px; left:650px; width:276px; height:49px; position:absolute; display:none}
#text5>div {
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/text5.png) no-repeat;
        /* IE hack */
    background:none\9; /* Targets IE only */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="Assets/puntacana/text5.png", sizingMethod="crop");}  



#house {top:-50px; left:-104px; width:1150px; height:539px; position:absolute; }
#house>div{
    width:100%; height:100%; display:none;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/5.jpg) no-repeat;
    }

#bar {top:0; left:0; width:960px; height:450px; position:absolute; display:none}
#bar>div{
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/4.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
#couple {top:0; left:0; width:960px; height:450px; position:absolute; display:none}
#couple>div{
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/3.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
#golf {top:0; left:0; width:960px; height:450px; position:absolute; display:none}
#golf>div{
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/2.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
#beach {top:0; left:0; width:960px; height:450px; position:absolute; display:none}
#beach>div{
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/1.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
#green {top:0; left:0; width:960px; height:450px; position:absolute; display:none}
#green>div{
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(Assets/puntacana/green.jpg) no-repeat;
    }



</style> 


<body> 


  <div id="box"> 
    <div id="top"> 
      <div id="jsbox"> 
        <div id="imageholder"> 

            <div id="house"><div></div></div> 
            <div id="bar"><div></div></div> 
            <div id="couple"><div></div></div> 
            <div id="golf"><div></div></div> 
            <div id="beach"><div></div></div> 
            <div id="green"><div></div></div> 

            <div class="palms" id="apalm1"><div id="palm1"></div></div> 
            <div class="palms" id="apalm2"><div id="palm2"></div></div> 
            <div class="palms" id="apalm3"><div id="palm3"></div></div> 
            <div class="palms" id="apalm4"><div id="palm4"></div></div> 
            <div class="palms" id="apalm5"><div id="palm5"></div></div> 
            <div class="palms" id="apalm6"><div id="palm6"></div></div> 
            <div class="palms" id="apalm7"><div id="palm7"></div></div> 
            <div class="palms" id="apalm8"><div id="palm8"></div></div> 


            <div id="icon"><div></div></div> 
            <div id="text2"><div></div></div> 
            <div id="text3"><div></div></div> 
            <div id="text4"><div></div></div> 
            <div id="text5"><div></div></div> 

        </div> 
      </div> 
      <div id="tab"></div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 


$(window).load(function () {    

    Opening();

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#icon').fadeIn(800)
        }, 1200);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#icon').fadeOut(800);
        $('#beach').fadeIn(600,
        function () {
            setTimeout (function () {$('#text2').fadeIn(1000)}, 700)
        });
    }, 3600);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#text2, #beach').fadeOut(900);
        $('#golf').fadeIn(900);
    }, 7100);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#golf').fadeOut(800);
        $('#couple').fadeIn(900,
        function () {
            $('#text3').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }, 9800);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#text3, #couple').fadeOut(800);
        $('#bar').fadeIn(800);
    }, 14200);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#bar').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#house>div').show().animate({
                    opacity:1,
                    scale: [.85, .85],

                }, 3800 );
    }, 16800);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#text4').fadeIn(800,
        function () {
            setTimeout (function () {
                $('#text4').fadeOut(600,
                    function () {
                        $('#text5').fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                )}, 1800);
            });

    }, 18200);


});


function Opening() {

        $('#palm1').transform({reflectY: true, rotate: '40deg'});
        $('#palm2').transform({rotate: '200deg'});
        $('#palm3').transform({reflectY: true,  rotate: '20deg'});
        $('#palm4').transform({reflectY: true,  rotate: '90deg'});
        $('#palm5').transform({reflectY: true,  rotate: '-90deg'});
        $('#palm6').transform({reflectY: false,  rotate: '24deg'});
        $('#palm7').transform({ rotate: '24deg'});
        $('#palm8').transform({ rotate: '-14deg'});

        $('.palms, #green').show().css({opacity:0}).animate({opacity:1}, 700);

        $('.palms>div').animate({ scale: [1.1, 1.1], rotate: '+=5deg'}, 2300, function () { swingBack(); });

            function swingBack() {
                $('.palms>div').animate({ scale: [1, 1], rotate: '-=5deg'}, 2300, function () {$(this).hide()}); 
                setTimeout (function() { $('.palms, #green').animate({opacity:0}, 1100)}, 1400)  
            };

};






</script> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You do realize that we can't actually run this and see right? It might be more useful if you setup a fiddle/jsbin and linked it here

Comment: check out the links in the question. you can see the flash and my js

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to run the code you are demoing, I can't suggest much. However, a word of advice that may help you:

I noticed that you make heavy use of jQuery's animate() method. I suggest you revisit to see if any of the animations can be done through CSS3 animations. These will be hardware-accelerated on the iPad - the javascript animations wont AFAIK.

Comment: FYI - he linked to the live animation in the post! but good advice re: css3 animations.

Comment: Thanks DustMason, just realized! Looking through the Flash movie, I do think a lot of the transitions can be done through CSS3 - specifically the background ones. Here's an example to help you get started. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg3/

Comment: Ok cool. I was trying to accomodate as many broswers as I could including IE8, which was making it so much more complicated. If I am able to only build it for safari, I will def look into css3 animations

Comment: You can use various methods to detect what browser your client is using. For iPads and Google chrome (and maybe FF), use CSS3 animations. For IE8, you're better off sticking with Flash to be honest.